# Should I emulate '.$promise' objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-resource

I am working on an admin app with AngularJS. The app fetches its data from the server using $resource. I end up with data objects containing '$promise' property to determine when the data has been fetched.
Everything's fine.

Now, this admin app can also create new objects. Those new objects are managed by the same controllers than the one that usually come from '$resource'.

So now I have 2 kind of objects:

- Objects with $promise property. I should use $promise.then() before manipulating them with full data
- Plain objects. They don't have a $promise property, their value is accessible instantly

I would like to reduce code and to have a single use-case, not having to check if object data is resolved, or if it is not a promise.

Is there any problem in building my 'plain' objects by adding them a '$promise' property which is already resolved to themselves? That way, I would always use 'myObject.$promise.then()'.

Is there any common pattern to handle this situation? I could not find any 'standard' method to create this kind of objects with Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) if unsure whether the object has a promise or not.

```
(obj.$promise ? obj.$promise || $q.when(objResult)).then(function(result){
          //handle success case.
          //Incase of object not having the $promise property result will be object itself
})
```

if the resultant property does not have a promise this will resolve with promise.

> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.

You do not need to always create a promise and attach it on the data that is being transferred, instead you could make your methods returns promise thus help you implement promise pattern and abstract out the promise logic on your service itself. Example:-

```
   function getCurrentUserData(userId){
       var defered = $q.defer();
       ... 
       //Check in my cache if this is already there, then get it from cache and resolve it
       defered.resolve(objectFromCache);
      //my else condition
      //It is not in cache so let me make the call.
      $http.get('myurl').then(function(result){
            //Do validation with data and if it doesnot match then reject it
            defered.reject(reason);
             //Else Do something with the data put it into the cache, mapping logic etc..
             defered.resolve(dto);


      }).catch(function(error){
            //do something with error and then reject
            defered.reject(reasonDerived);
      });
      return defered.promise;
   }
```

Here is a simplified and less explicit version (Credit: Benjamin Gruenbaum):

```
var cached = null;
function getCurrentUserData(userId){
    return cached = cached || $http.get('myurl').then(function(result){
        if(isNotValid(result)) return $q.reject(reason); // alternatively `throw`
        return transformToDto(result);
    }, function(response){
     if(checkforsomethingonstatusandreject)
       return $q.reject('Errored Out')
     //do some actions to notify the error scenarios and return default actions
     return someDefaults; });
    }
```

You can of course `return $q.reject(derivedReason)` here rather than returning the reason and transform it based on further checks, the idea is caching the promise rather than the value. This also has the advantage of not making multiple http requests if the method is called before it returns once.

Now you could always do:-

```
    getCurrentUserData(userid).then(function(user){

    }).catch(function(error){

    });
```

Promises can be chained through as well. So you could also do this:-

```
   return $resource('myresource').$promise.then(function(result){
          //Do some mapping and return mapped data
         return mappedResult;
    });
```

Comment: Mmmm, very interesting. Much cleaner. But I find it strange that $resource returns 'hybrid' objects, not promise, but containing their promise in '$promise'. I thought there would be a way to generate the '$promise' on any object

Comment: @ChristopheFondacci You can create your own promise using $q.defer and send that promise from your service, that way you can be consistent. I will update my answer. I would try not to attach a promise object to the DTO, but possibly my opinion i guess. :)

Comment: This is too bad that $q.when() does not understand 'promising' values returned by $resource. This would have been very useful. Anyway you are right, the best method seems to create a method converting anything to a promise and call it when needed. This is actually the purpose of $q... too bad they don't support $resource-generated objects :(

Comment: @ChristopheFondacci ah. i didn't know that.. Haven't used much $resource myself. isn't the `$promise` same as $q promise? Basically if you do `$q.when(obj.$promise || objResult).then` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes your $q.when() works, I mean `$q.when(obj)` would have been nicer than `$q.when(obj.$promise || obj)`. It would make sense that `$q.when()` could handle objects returned by $resource (I must say I hate that my code relies on the '$promise' property :)

Comment: Please fix that ugly deferred anti pattern. You can simply `return $q.when(objFromCache || $http(...` :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum of course you can (That is what my example and simply the documentation of $q.when says) :D. It is explicit enough IMHO. Watch closely to my second example you are rejecting the promise from within the success of $http You cannot just achieve that by returning httpPromise, unless you use static reject from within and chain through `then` skipping success. I would be really enlightened to see a less ugly pattern... if you can share. :(

Comment: I've added an edit, let me know what you think. It'd be preferable to avoid `return $q.reject` and instead `throw` but Angular calls `$exceptionHandler` when you do that which is undesirable.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Enlightened.. :) Yes this is much better, i could not recollect what was the issue i was having with this approach, one thing for sure is that its ability to work with success/error.But i have updated the answer to handle error as well. Inorder to avoid multiple request i have been caching the defered promise that was created once, and clearing up when needed. But unfortly one way or the other we end up using explicit reject. Thanks for the update.. Let me rewind back to see the issue i was having....

Comment: Why are you explicitly returning a `$q.reject`? Rejections are like exceptions, that's a beauty of it - they propagate so you don't have to manually like you do with callbacks :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thats just for short ciruting.. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58267/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-psl).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Its blocked for me.. :(

Comment: Oh ok then. What I said is that I don't understand how it's 'short circuiting' anything and I asked if you could explain that. All it does from what I can tell is just override the (meaningful) rejection value with a fixed string.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, Hope it is clear now... Does that make sense.

Comment: I think it's still redundant given the circumstance (OP doesn't have anything like it in his code but I think I understand it now, thanks.

Comment: Sorry. How redundant.. You need a catch call back for status errors (beyond 200-300 range)and probably would need to parse for a specific status and error response data. Pretty much legit i guess!! Anyways it is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

A+ promises should offer a static method:

```
Promise.resolve(val);
```

...which generates a pre-resolved promise. You should return one of these if your promises library offers this. Great. I do this frequently to avoid interface duplication.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am using AngularJS. But yes I am looking for exactly this kind of method...for angular promises. Will update my question to explicitly mention angular

Comment: EcmaScript 6 standard promises have that method. A+ promises don't. A+ specifies only `then`